# Is there a way to check whether a value equals 0 or 1, with a single comparison?

Tags: php, algorithm, optimization, bit-manipulation

I have a lot of pieces of code like

```
    case 'add':
    {   
        $succeeded = $wpdb->insert('coms', 
                                   array('name'=>$name,'story'=>$story,'imgurl'=>$imgurl)
                                   ) === 1;
        break;
    }
```

and I just realized that I need to change them all to compare against both 1 and 0. They would all be like

```
        $numRowsAffected = $wpdb->insert('coms', 
                                   array('name'=>$name,'story'=>$story,'imgurl'=>$imgurl)
                                   );
        $succeeded = $numRowsAffected === 1 || $numRowsAffected === 0;
```

**HOWEVER**, I'm wondering whether there is a more compact, elegant and efficient way of checking a value against 1 or 0. Can I do it in one fell swoop with bitshift operators?

Comment: How about `in_array($numRowsAffected, array(1, 0), TRUE);`?

Comment: Not necessarily more elegant and certainly less efficient, but `in_array($numRowsAffected, [0,1])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($value | 1 === 1)
```

I think that should do the trick.

Comment: Haha! Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind. I realize that might not work because is in this case `$value` can be `false` (hence the `===`). I'm not sure what `false | 1` would evaluate to ...

Comment: Then it's not going to work in one statement. Any math comparison will cast the value into a number, and false will get converted to 0. Methods that return multiple types drive me a little crazy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in_array`:

```
$succeeded = in_array($numRowsAffected, array(0, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether `variable & 0b1111111111111110` is zero, where you adapt the lenght of the bit pattern to the maximum size of the variable.